# Getting "The fcm.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default" when running a Google Cloud Function locally

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to test a Google Cloud Function that sends messages to users. The relevant code is:

```py
cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    "projectId": "redacted_project_id",
})

@functions_framework.http
def send_messages(request):
    fcm_tokens = request_json.get('fcmTokens')
    message_text = request_json.get('message')

    message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
        data={'message': message_text},
        tokens=fcm_tokens,
    )

    response = messaging.send_multicast(message)
    if response.success_count > 0:
        logging.info("Message sent successfully")
        return jsonify({'success': True, 'message': 'Message sent successfully!'}), 200
    else:
        logging.warning("Failed to send message. Responses: %s", len(response.responses))
        for index, resp in enumerate(response.responses):
            if not resp.success:
                logging.error("Failed to send message to token %s: %s", fcm_tokens[index], resp.exception)
        return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': 'Failed to send message'}), 500
```

I'm running this locally with `functions-framework --target=send_messages`. When calling the function, I see the output:

```
WARNING - Failed to send message. Responses: 2
ERROR - Failed to send message to token e7...N6T2:APA...0bh: Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. The fcm.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default. To learn how to set your quota project, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds .
ERROR - Failed to send message to token banana: Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. The fcm.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default. To learn how to set your quota project, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds .
```

<sup>(Redacted part of the token)</sup>

I have no idea why this is happening-

- The page linked in the error says to run `gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project YOUR_PROJECT` (which I did)
- `echo $GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` returns the correct project id
- `cat /home/$USER/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` has the correct `quota_project_id` (was set by running `gcloud auth application-default login`)
- My role in the Google Cloud Project is "Owner"

Comment: Change your code to use a service account instead of user credentials, which ADC is selecting for your app.